# Why is Typescript not correctly inferring the type of an array’s element?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have an object, `RollingStockSelectorParams` that contains arrays.

I’m trying to get TypeScript to infer the type of elements of the choosen array `additionalRsParams[title]`

Primary question: why is `ValueType<RollingStockSelectorParams, T>` `unknown` here ?

and out of curiosity, why does indexOf consider that it’s `Comfort` even though it can’t know the actual type at compile time.

`indexOf(searchElement: Comfort, fromIndex?: number | undefined)`

> Argument of type 'ValueType<RollingStockSelectorParams, T>' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'Comfort'. Type 'unknown' is not
> assignable to type 'Comfort'.(2345)

```
export type ValueType<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends (infer U)[] ? U : never;

export type Comfort = 'AC' | 'HEATING' | 'STANDARD';

export type RollingStockSelectorParams = {
  comfortLevels: Comfort[];
  tractionModes: string[];
  electricalProfiles: (string | null)[];
  powerRestrictions: (string | null)[];
};

  function f<T extends keyof RollingStockSelectorParams>(
    value: ValueType<RollingStockSelectorParams, T>,
    title: T,
    additionalRsParams: RollingStockSelectorParams
  ) {
    const index = additionalRsParams[title].indexOf(value);
  }
```

Comment: Strangely, it works when `RollingStockSelectorParams` is expressed as a mapped type. https://tsplay.dev/WJ1O5m

Comment: This looks like two questions with two answers and thus needs more focus; could you please [edit] to specify exactly which question is primary?

Comment: See prev comment. • If "first off, why": `additionalRsParams[title]` is widened to its constraint when you access `indexOf` and becomes a union of functions, and a union of functions requires an intersection of its parameters to be safe (see [docs](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)). • If "and why", it's because `value`'s type is a generic conditional type and the compiler doesn't try to evaluate those.  • Either way, the "right" way to do this would be as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/NnMVBw).

Comment: See prev comment.  I'm happy to flesh out the answer to one of those in an answer post, if you agree it addresses the question.  Let me know which, and let me know if I'm missing something about the question that would prevent my suggestions from applying.

Comment: @jcalz main issue here was the `ValueType<RollingStockSelectorParams, T>` being `unknown`. I edited the question. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ValueType<T, K>` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and since `value` is of type `ValueType<RollingStockSelectorParams, K>` for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `K` inside the body of `f()`, then `value` is a *generic conditional type*.  And the TypeScript type checker generally *defers* evaluation of such types.  It doesn't try to perform a lot of higher order or abstract reasoning on what sorts of values might or might not be assignable to it.  It just treats the type as a mostly opaque thing, and complains if you try to assign anything to it unless the type is the *same* opaque thing.

What ends up happening when you try to use it the way you're doing, is that the type checker just gives up and says it's not assignable.  The particular form of `ValueType<T, K>` uses [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to compute the result, and since the returned `U` type is [implicitly constrained to `unknown`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown), the compiler just says it can't be sure that it will work because (for all it can "see") the type of `U` might be as wide as `unknown`.

There are plenty of [GitHub issues about generic conditional types](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2FTypeScript+%22generic+conditional%22&type=issues) where this sort of behavior is mentioned.  Essentially there's not a lot that can be done for the general case, although sometimes specific instances can be supported.  Probably the closest to the current example is [microsoft/TypeScript#52489](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52489).

---

If you know you've got an array type, you don't need to use conditional type inference to get its element type.  You can just [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `number`:

```
export type ValueType<T extends Record<K, any[]>, K extends keyof T> =
    T[K][number]
```

which still doesn't work for your use case, but at least now the compiler would see that it's `string | null` as opposed to `unknown`.

---

Since SO questions should focus on a single question, I won't go as deeply into your secondary question.  The short answer for why `indexOf()` expects `Comfort` is because that's the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the possible element types, `Comfort & string & (string | null)` is just `Comfort`.  The compiler can't follow your logic for treating `additionalRsParams[title].indexOf()` as *generic*, so it widens to its specific constraint, yielding a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of functions, and [a union of functions needs an intersection of arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types).

---

The "correct" way to write your code, according to recommendations in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), is to base everything on generic indexing into a basic key-value interface or mapped types on that interface.  It looks like this:

```
interface Rolling {
    comfortLevels: Comfort,
    tractionModes: string,
    electricalProfiles: string | null,
    powerRestrictions: string | null
}

function g<K extends keyof Rolling>(
    value: Rolling[K],
    title: K,
    additionalRsParams: { [K in keyof Rolling]: Rolling[K][] }
) {
    const index = additionalRsParams[title].indexOf(value);
}
```

But again, I won't go into detail, because the question as asked is not "how can I do this so the compiler understands it", but "why is `value` being treated as `unknown`"?

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#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-GAuzFTIQ3oOUFSVM0CQg6cdT1A1uCNRULAQ-ELR9LAIPtR1FU9aD4M9AlcKtLARCfEQg3oaC4HxCM5iUdhOFjcc1WzXN8wsLiCXWCCjw7UZu17fsdywIdZyVFk4GkVd2KWOMKwJGR+K-QTZEMOAnwXH8UjSeBz3XZlN0k+hd1kw94mPM81yvG87zwB8aKAA)